# Get DOM elements quantity in Angular(4) application

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom, socket.io

I am developing application using angular.

And I show notifications from notification array. They come from socket connection.

```
<div class="notifications-container">
  <div *ngFor='let notification of notifications'>

        <div class="notification-messege" title="{{notification.body.content}}">
            {{notification.body.content}}
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I hide, if there are more than 5 notifications?

Comment: Do you want to hide the `notification-messege` ?

Comment: Some answers below show solutions with *ngIf. If it were me, I would create a second, filtered array that contains only 5 items. Then I'd bind my template to that filtered array.

Comment: `notifications | slice: 0: 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to display first 5 notifications. You could use index and *ngIf.

```
<div class="notifications-container">
  <div *ngFor='let notification of notifications; let i = index'>

        <div *ngIf = "i<5" class="notification-messege" title="{{notification.body.content}}">
            {{notification.body.content}}
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Using [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)

```
<div class="notifications-container">
  <div *ngFor='let notification of notifications | slice:0:5;'>

        <div class="notification-messege" title="{{notification.body.content}}">
            {{notification.body.content}}
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

To display last five notifications:

```
<div class="notifications-container">
      <div *ngFor='let notification of (notifications | slice:notifications.lenght- 5)'>    
            <div class="notification-messege" title="{{notification.body.content}}">
                {{notification.body.content}}
            </div>    
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: It show first 5 items, but I want to show last 5 items

Comment: Just get the subset of last five elements   <div *ngFor='let notification of notifications | slice:notifications.length-5:otifications.length;'>

Comment: Updated answer to display last five notifications.  What do you mean my vice versa? Give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the notifications you want to show with Angular's `*ngIf` directive.

Modify your code to the following:

```
<div class="notifications-container">
  <div *ngFor='let notification of notifications'>

        <div *ngIf="noitications.length<=5" class="notification-messege" title="{{notification.body.content}}">
            {{notification.body.content}}
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Notice `*ngIf="noitications.length<=5"`, here if the number of notifications which is stored in the `notifications` array is more than 5 then the `notification-message` will not be shown.

Comment: It show first 5 items, but I want to show last 5 items